# Angular 4 is not passing data to server?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-components

I have data printed in service from component. But when I post this to the back-end, it's getting empty object. What is the correct approach to send data to api using Angular 2+ ?

app.component.ts

```
this.searchService.getSearch(this.searchObj1).subscribe(searchObj => {
         // this.detailService.changeMessage(searchObj.data)
       consle.log(searchObj);
        });
```

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getSearch(searchObj:{}) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(searchObj);
    console.log('Fac',body);
    return this.http.post('/api/search',body).map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

SERVER

```
    const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');

// declare axios for making http requests
const axios = require('axios');
const API = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
    router.post('/search', (req, response) => {
      // Get posts from the mock api
      console.log('CLientReq',req.body);
       request.post('http://sla/service/getHistoricEvents',
       { json: true,
         body: req.body,
         proxy:'http://one.proxy.att.com:8080',
         headers: {
         "content-type": "application/json",
         "authorization": "Basic bTA5NDg1QGNvbXMuYXR0LmNvbTpjYnVzTVNAMjAxNw=="
        }
       },
       function(err, res, body) {
         response.status(200).json(body);
       }
       );
    });
```

Comment: try using httpclient

Comment: Don't stringify your body. Http (and HttpClient) do that for you, and specify the correct content type. Show the code calling this method, show what is logged, show the server code handling the request, show how you determine that the received object is empty.

Comment: And Catch errors: 
      .catch(this.handleError); "

Comment: added more code to question

Comment: please share where you are calling getSearch()

Comment: Does the browser console show any CORS issues? I don't see any CORS configuration in your server

Comment: its there in `app.component.ts`

Comment: @JBNizet thanks removing stringify resolved the issue thanks to all